# paste plain text ajax custom editor chrome issue

Tags: c#, ajax, text, editor, paste

I used below code to paste plain text in my Ajax Custom Editor. It works fine with IE and Firefox. but chrome got screwed.

please help me!

Also, is there a way to access custom editor buttons via c# code, to apply events or get set values

```
Sys.Application.add_load( function ()
{

    editor = $find('<%=Myeditor.ClientID%>');  // Editor's ID="myEditor"
    if (editor != null) {
        var editPanel = editor.get_editPanel();
        editPanel.set_noPaste(true);

    }


    //---------------------------------------------------

    if (Sys.Extended.UI.HTMLEditor.isIE) {
        var designMode = Sys.Extended.UI.HTMLEditor.ActiveModeType.Design;
        var designPanel = editPanel.get_modePanels()[designMode];


        designPanel.captureInDesign = function (ev) {
            if (ev.type == "keydown" && ev.ctrlKey && !ev.altKey) {
                // key event
                if (String.fromCharCode(ev.keyCode).toLowerCase() == "v") {
                    this._commonPaste(ev);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

});
```